# Why won't my php form work submitting to my sql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress, forms

```html
<html>
   
   <head>
      <title>Add a New Open Mic</title>

   </head>
   
   <body>
      <?php
         if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*";
$password = "*";
$dbname = "mlcarelo_wrdp2";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
            
            if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
   $State= addslashes ($_POST['State']);
   $City= addslashes ($_POST['City']);
   $Place= addslashes ($_POST['Place']);
   $Address= addslashes ($_POST['Address']);
   $Day= addslashes ($_POST['Day']);
   $Time= addslashes ($_POST['Time']);
   $Host= addslashes ($_POST['Host']);
   $Contact= addslashes ($_POST['Contact Information']);

            }else {
   $State= addslashes ($_POST['State']);
   $City= addslashes ($_POST['City']);
   $Place= addslashes ($_POST['Place']);
   $Address= addslashes ($_POST['Address']);
   $Day= addslashes ($_POST['Day']);
   $Time= addslashes ($_POST['Time']);
   $Host= addslashes ($_POST['Host']);
   $Contact= addslashes ($_POST['Contact Information']);
            }
            
            
            
            $sql = "INSERT INTO 'responses' (State,City, Place, 
               Address, Day, Time, Host, Contact Information)VALUES('$State','$City','$Place', '$Address', '$Day', '$Time', '$Host', '$Contact');
               
            mysql_select_db('mlcarelo_wrdp2');
            $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
            
            if(! $retval ) {
               die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            
            echo "Entered data successfully\n";
            
            mysql_close($conn);
         }else {
           
            }
               <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
                  <table width = "400" border = "0" cellspacing = "1" 
                     cellpadding = "2">
                  
                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">State</td>
                        <td><input name = "State" type = "text" 
                           id = "State"></td>
                     </tr>
                  
                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">City</td>
                        <td><input name = "City" type = "text" 
                           id = "City"></td>
                     </tr>
                  
                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Place</td>
                        <td><input name = "Place" type = "text" 
                           id = "Place"></td>
                     </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Address</td>
                        <td><input name = "Address" type = "text" 
                           id = "Address"></td>
                     </tr>
      <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Day</td>
                        <td><input name = "Day" type = "text" 
                           id = "Day"></td>
                     </tr>
      <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Time</td>
                        <td><input name = "Time" type = "text" 
                           id = "Time"></td>
                     </tr>
      <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Host</td>
                        <td><input name = "Host" type = "text" 
                           id = "Host"></td>
                     </tr>
      <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Contact Information</td>
                        <td><input name = "Contact Information" type = "text" 
                           id = "Contact Information"></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                     </tr>
                  
                    
                  
                  </table>
               </form>
            
            <?
   
   </body>
</html>
```

How can I get my form to work so users may input information and submit it to enter into the sql database? I don't realy understand Form= action. I am using wordpress. I have successfully pulled tables to display from my database so I know that my beginning of php coding is correct and the query should be correct.

Comment: nowhere found form submission code!

Comment: **Typo**:- You missed end string in your $sql. write '$Contact')";

Comment: How should the visitor tell the page to process the information? Is there a submit button with the name "add"?

Comment: You are connecting via `mysqli` and are trying to query with `mysql_`. Those are two different libs.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_`. Use `mysqli_` only:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO responses (State, City, Place, Address, Day, Time, Host, ContactInformation) VALUES ('$State', '$City', '$Place', '$Address', '$Day', '$Time', '$Host', '$Contact')";
$retval = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(! $retval ) {
    die('Could not enter data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Also there are several syntax errors in your query, e.g. table names aren't enclosed by `' '`. Note that you don't need to use `mysqli_select_db`, you are doing this within you connection string already. I'm sure your column `Contact Information` doesn't have a whitespace in your table, so you'll need to correct this, too. I've used `ContactInformation`, make sure this is correct.

SIDENOTE:

Inserting data this way is wide open to sql-injection. Use prepared statements instead!!

Comment: Could I have more example of syntax errors? I have changed everything thats come up so far. When I refreshed my page peoples answers are disappearing and my topics being downvoted

Comment: There was another one before '$Day'. Why don't you simply look what mysqli_error outputs?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ‘<‘ in /home3/mlcarelock/public_html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/insert_php.php(48) : eval()’d code on line 50